# Not able to use Datacontext to bind data to Callisto livetiles

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml

This is the Live Tile template I am using

```
<callisto:LiveTile x:Name="liveTile1" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0"
         ItemsSource="{Binding}"
         BorderBrush="White" BorderThickness="1"
         Margin="15" Background="#FFCAD83E">
                <callisto:LiveTile.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Grid>
                            <StackPanel>
                                <TextBlock Text="Temp" FontWeight="SemiBold" 
                                           FontSize="25" FontFamily="Segoe UI Semibold" 
                                           Margin="10,20,0,0">
                                </TextBlock>
                                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="0,20,0,0">
                                   <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" x:Name="CrudeStMainTankName"
                                              FontWeight="Light"
                                              FontSize="20"
                                              FontFamily="Segoe UI Semilight"
                                              Margin="0,0,0,0">
                                   </TextBlock>
                                   <TextBlock Text="{Binding Value}" x:Name="CrudeStMainTankValue"
                                              FontWeight="Light"
                                              FontSize="20" 
                                              FontFamily="Segoe UI Semilight"
                                              Margin="0,00,0,0">
                                    </TextBlock>
                                </StackPanel>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </Grid>
                    </DataTemplate>
              </callisto:LiveTile.ItemTemplate>
 </callisto:LiveTile>
```

This is how I am assigning my DataContext to this live Tile

```
liveTile1.DataContext = cds.ComponentCollection[0];
```

I have tried to debug it but I am going nowhere.

Now cds.ComponentCollection[0] retrieves an item from the collection contaning name, type and value and from this collection item , I am binding Textblock property Name to Item Property Name and Textblock property Value to Item Property Value.
Can anybody please help me on how to get this working?

Answer (score 1):

`LiveTile` is an `ItemsControl` therefore you need to set its `ItemsSource` property to a collection. With your XAML this means you need to set the `DataContext` to complete `cds.ComponentCollection` not only to its first item, i.e.:

```
liveTile1.DataContext = cds.ComponentCollection;
```